# How to get position attribute in shader

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I'm really new to gl and trying to understand how to give my shaders a position attribute. A library I was using somehow made it so I got a vec3 position for each pixel of a surface. Does anyone know how I could achieve that? I believe if I pass in an attribute or uniform then it will be that value for every pixel that the shader processes. I'm wondering how to get it to increment as it shades the area.

This is how I'm drawing my surface:

```js
  draw(gl) {
    gl.useProgram(this.prog);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.coordsBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.coords, gl.STREAM_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.coordsAttrib, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.coordsAttrib);

    gl.uniform2fv(this.inTexCoordUni, this.inTexCoord);
    gl.uniform1f(this.rotationUni, this.rotation);
    gl.uniform2fv(this.dimensionsUni, this.dimensions);
    gl.uniform1f(this.borderWidthUni, this.borderWidth);
    gl.uniform2fv(this.positionUni, this.position);
    
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
  }
```

Here are the shaders:

```c
precision mediump float;

uniform vec2 position1;
uniform vec2 textureSize_;
uniform vec2 inTexCoord;
uniform float rotation;
varying vec2 texCoord;
varying vec2 center;

attribute vec2 coords1;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(coords1, 0.0, 1.0);

  float inX = (inTexCoord.x/textureSize_.x);
  float inY = (inTexCoord.y/textureSize_.y);

  float x = position1.x*2.5/textureSize_.x+inX;
  float y = position1.y*2.5/textureSize_.y+inY;
      
  float s = sin(rotation);
  float c = cos(rotation);

  float dX = x - inX;
  float dY = y - inY;
      
  float newX = inX + c * dX - s * dY;
  float newY = inY + s * dX + c * dY;

  center.x = inTexCoord.x/textureSize_.x;
  center.y = inTexCoord.y/textureSize_.y;
  texCoord.x = newX;
  texCoord.y = newY;
}
```

```c
precision mediump float;

uniform vec2 textureSize_;
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform vec2 dimensions;
uniform float borderWidth;
varying vec2 texCoord;
varying vec2 center;
void main() {
  float dx = texCoord.x - center.x;
  float dy = texCoord.y - center.y;
  float dist = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  float radius = (dimensions.x*2.5/textureSize_.x)/2.0-0.003;
  if(dist > radius)
    discard;
  else if(dist > radius-borderWidth)
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  else
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(texture1, texCoord).rgb, 1.0);
 }
```

Comment: Also, what is your shader code?

Comment: Uniforms are per-mesh, not per-pixel, by the way.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget Added shader code. And oh okay I didn't know that.

Comment: How do you want your uniform to "increment as it shades the area"? Also, why are you transforming the texcoord, not the position? The *position* should be transformed, the texcoord should remain the same.

Comment: I don't think it will work as a uniform. I think I need an attribute. I'm using a uniform now because I don't know how else do to it. I'm curious how to get the position of each pixel in the vertex shader.

Comment: You can't get the position of a *pixel* in the *vertex* shader. The vertex shader is for vertices, not pixels! If you the pixel position, get it in the fragment shader. There you can use `gl_FragCoord`.

Comment: Understood. So does that mean the library (threejs) created vertices for each discrete point on a plane? I somehow doubt it as that would be terribly inefficient? This code was working perfectly in threejs, where it supplies a position vector attribute for each point on the surface.

Answer (score 2):

The fragment shader allows for individual pixel access.

A good example of this is a fullscreen quad. Even though only 4 vertices (4 vec2 positions) get sent to the vertex shader, the shaders do work behind-the-scenes on "pos = position"...

```
#version 450 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
out vec2 pos;

void main() {
    pos = position;
    gl_Position = vec4(position[0], position[1], 0, 1);
}
```

You can do something like this in the fragment shader:

```
#version 450 core
out vec4 final_color;
in vec2 pos;

void main()
{
    if (pos[0] + 0.001 > pos[1] && pos[0] - 0.001 < pos[1]){
        final_color = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    else{
        final_color = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

To render the following...

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How do you set the `position` vector?

Comment: It looks like you're already passing your position data "this.coords" in glBufferData() with its associated glVertexAttribPointer() to the shader. Creating a uniform with positions is redundant.

Comment: Okay I didn't know if that was sufficient. I still don't get how `pos` gets updated then if the function is only run for every vertex.